# show only values if checkbox value is true

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data list in column B1:B4 as below
Section_A
Section_B
Section_C
Section_D
in-front of these values in column A1:A4 I have 4 check boxes placed.(form control type not active X).I want generate only clicked values to column C.Example:After first check box and third check box clicked Show Section_A and Section_C.(In column C  need this result without blank cell between Section_A and Section_C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LARGE method for which you would need to add one more column.

1st: link your checkbox with cells in column A so that respective cell will give TRUE or FALSE when the checkbox is ticked or unticked respectively.

2nd: Move your column B data into column C and in front of each cell in column A, Assign weight in column B(You can Hide this column If you don't want this to be visible).

3rd: Use Large Function in column D as shown in Below SS.

[image]

change the color of cells in column A to white and Hide Column B, it would look something like this.

[image]

and your work is done.

Comment: welcome @SandaruwanWeerasinghe, if the answer worked for you then please select it as accepted answer.